# textarea value does not update when onchange event takes place on select option

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, onchange

I wanted to why the values of my textarea are not updated when a user selects from pull-down menu?  am I using the conditional for string values incorrect?

Here is what I want to happen; wen a user selects the Filer Changes options I want the textarea to be populated with a default value, and/or allow the user to update the value, post it to a php page.

```
 <html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <title></title>
   <script type="text/javascript"><!--
         function updateDescImpact() {
         var changeSel = document.changeform.changeType;
         var changeType = parseInt(changeSel.options[changeSel.selectedIndex].value);
         if(changeType == "Filer Changes") {
            document.changeform.description.value = "This is the Filer Change Description";
            document.changeform.impact.value = "This is the Filer Changes impact statement";
         } else if(changeType == "DNS Changes" ) {
            document.changeform.description.value = "This is the DNS Change Description";
           document.changeform.impact.value = "This is the DNS Changes impact statement";
      } else {
             document.changeform.description.value = "";
             document.changeform.impact.value = "";
      }
     }         

     // -->
     </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="changeform" method="post" action="">
    <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
    <td width="18%">Change Type</td>
    <td width="82%"><select name="ChangeType" id="ChangeType" onchange="updateDescImpact()">
    <option value="Filer Changes">Filer Changes</option>
    <option value="DNS Changes">DNS Changes</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td>Description</td>
     <td>
     <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="50" rows="10"> This needs to be updated</textarea></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>

     <td>Impact</td>
     <td>

      <textarea name="impact" id="impact" cols="50" rows="10">This needs to be updated</textarea>
      </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Musa said, JavaScript is case sensitive so `document.changeform.changeType;` should be `document.changeform.ChangeType;`

However that alone won't make it work.

on the second line in `updateDescImpact()` you've got:

`var changeType = parseInt(changeSel.options[changeSel.selectedIndex].value);`

You are trying to parse the value as an integer but then trying to compare it to a sting on the next line.

Be rid of that data conversion and you shouldn't have any problems:

`var changeType = changeSel.options[changeSel.selectedIndex].value;`

Comment: I think that's the issue, `parseInt('Filer Changes')` gives `NaN`, which isn't equal to anything.

Comment: Thanks you very much Musa and Benjamin the the major issue was I was trying to parse the changeSel value as a integer.

Comment: Glad to help! If you would be so kind, please select an answer and close the question?

Comment: I selected the answer, but how do you close the question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong with your code, the following works fine. I've made some minor changes:

1. remove useless HTML comment delimiters in the script element
2. pass a reference to the select from the listener
3. more efficient form access
4. more efficient select element vlaue  access
5. added a submit button

   ```
     function updateDescImpact(el) {
       var form = el.form;
       var changeType = el.value;

       if (changeType == "Filer Changes") {
         form.description.value = "This is the Filer Change Description";
         form.impact.value = "This is the Filer Changes impact statement";

       } else if (changeType == "DNS Changes" ) {
         form.description.value = "This is the DNS Change Description";
         form.impact.value = "This is the DNS Changes impact statement";

       } else {
         form.description.value = "";
         form.impact.value = "";
       }
     }         

   </script>
   ```

   ```
   <form name="changeform" method="post" action="">
     <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
       <tr>
         <td width="18%">Change Type</td>
         <td width="82%"><select name="ChangeType" id="ChangeType" onchange="updateDescImpact(this)">
           <option value="Filer Changes">Filer Changes</option>
           <option value="DNS Changes">DNS Changes</option>
         </select></td>
       </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>Description</td>
         <td>
         <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="50" rows="10"> This needs to be updated</textarea></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>Impact</td>
         <td><textarea name="impact" id="impact" cols="50" rows="10">This needs to be updated</textarea></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="2"><input type="submit">
     </table>
   </form>
   ```

Comment: my orginal does have an submit button,  the issue was I was trying to parse a integer  `Var changeType = parseInt(changeSel.options[changeSel.selectedIndex].value);`  I have removed the parseInt and it resolved the issue